# How to create multi-gradient reflection on Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, gradient, gradient-mesh

I want to replicate this multi-coloured reflection on illustrator. I tried using feathering and free-form gradient, but haven't had any success.

[image: Text Reflection]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I have to be honest with you here, I don't think this was made in Illustrator. Have a look at 3d modelling software instead, such as Blender (which is free).  There's a [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) if you get stuck.